# TestNG AssertEquals double - good number to put for a double?

Tags: java, testng, assertions

Using TestNG's `Assert.assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)`, what would be a good number to use for a delta using the following numbers (assertion failed because there is no delta)

```
AssertionError: expected [121.97] but found [121.96999999999998]
```

I tried using `1`, `.01`, and `.001`, but all three passed.  I want to keep the allowance for success to be very small (in other words, if the "actual numbers" (from my perspective anyways) were 121.97 and 121.96 I want the test to to fail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your test to fail for `121.97` and `121.96`...
try using delta that is smaller than
`|121.97 - 121.96| = 0.01`.
How about:

```
final double DELTA = 0.001;
assertEquals(121.97, 121.96, DELTA);
```

Output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [121.96] but found [121.97]
Expected :121.96
Actual   :121.97
```

In general case... if you want your assertion to fail for `a` and `b`,
use delta that is smaller than `|a - b|`.